# Can an open circle be marked with an asymptote?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

If I have a function:
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x + 1,  & \text{if $x$ < 0} \\
x - 1, & \text{if $x$ > 0}
\end{cases}$$

Creating the graph:
[Graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3uGc.png), would it be correct to place an asymptote at $x=0$, or must you use open circles at $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

For discontinuities this is my favoured presentation :

- a semi-open circle at the discontinuity $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=1$
- a filled circle at the continuity point $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=-2$ and $f(1)=-2$

For the function you gave in your post, this would be two semi-open circles since your function is not defined at $x=0$.

[image]

When the function can be extended by continuity but has a hole, i.e. a point where the function is not defined, the use a small not filled circle like above.

$\lim\limits_{x\to 5}f(x)$ exists, but $f(5)$ is undefined.

Finally asymptotes can be marked like the pink dashed lines above when the function either has limits in $\pm\infty$ or takes infinite values at a specific $x_0$ ($x_0=-2$ on the picture).

Answer (score 0):

You must use open circles.  Placing a vertical(I guess, you didn't specify) asymptote at $x=0$ would say that the graph of the function approaches infinity as $x$ gets closer to 0, which it does not.

Comment: I mean the _equation_ $x=0$, so yes you're correct in assuming a vertical asymptote. But does it have to approach _infinity_ to be an asymptote? For example in the graph of an exponential approaches a value $a$ and that warrants an asymptote. Cheers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you have a vertical asymptote at $x=a$, then the $f(x)$ must approach infinity as $x$ approaches $a$ (from at least one side).  If you have a horizontal asymptote at $y=a$, then $f(x)$ must approach $a$ as $x$ approaches either $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Well that answers the question, thanks!