# How can I graph this function?

Tags: graphing-functions

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & |x|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\\
3 & \frac{\pi}{2}<|x|\leq \pi
\end{cases}$$

[image]
Maybe someone can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: would be great to have your thoughts and attempts. In particular, do you have any partucular doubt that prevents you from completing the task?

Comment: Consider cases with respect to absolute value.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for comments. This is what I tried: https://prnt.sc/13zrm3i

Comment: It seems you got it right, maybe just add semi-circles to identify strict inequalities and filled circles for loose inequalities to the ends of the segments and it will be perfect.(e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2423560/399263)

Comment: @zwim Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph is correct though I think it's good to highlight what value is taken when $|x|=\frac{\pi}2$.

However, what you wrote at the side is not correct.

$$\frac{\pi}{2}<|x|\le \pi$$

consists of two regions, $-\pi \le x < -\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac{\pi}2 < x \le \pi$.